# как изменить формат вывода календаря с понедельника по воскресенье

Tags: javascript, calendar, format, momentjs

Как изменить формат вывода календаря с понедельника по воскресенье календарь. Который находиться по ссылке

```
[https://codepen.io/N_QiXin/pen/PrVLGJ][1]
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет. При переключении начинается с понедельника, а вот при инициализации первый день воскресенье откуда-то берется, к сожалению нет времени разбираться:

В прототипе getWeek:

```
Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
   if (!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
     this.week = createElement("div", "week");
     this.month.appendChild(this.week);
   }
};
```

Заменить:

```
if (!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
```

На:

```
if (!this.week || day.day() === 1) {
```